# dpkg offline How to complete the job

Tags: software-installation, wine

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.ostechnix.com/install-softwares-offline-ubuntu-16-04/) on how to download packages offline but there is a caveat; you have to already have Synaptic install on the offline device. My goal is to install wine. I am having a hard time with my WIFI on my new computer. It works fine on Windows, not so much on the Ubuntu side. At any rate, I bought a USB for detecting WIFI in hopes that this will help but it is a Windows program. I have managed to install the programs on the computer, I just don't know what do do make that productive.[[image: Synaptic]]I tried putting all of the files in here:

```
mv *.deb synaptic.sh /var/cache/apt/archives
```

I also changed directories at this point.

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
```

But I ran into trouble when I attempted to install the program like so.

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

At the very top it reads that synaptic is installed, but there are no dependencies.

[image: Error][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv6Xv.png) How do I finish the job? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Move all the packages into /var/cache/apt/archives/ , so apt knows where to look for them. Then tell apt to install Synaptic.

Comment: With sudo apt-get install synaptic? That did not work, would you please elaborate? I did manage to move the files, but I was still unsuccessful.

Comment: You are installing a deb file already on your system: `sudo apt install /full/path/to/complete_package_name.deb` If something does not work, please provide full output - we are not psychic.

Comment: @BJsgoodlife your end goal is to fix wifi using wine, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Installing `wine` will NOT help you fix wifi. Why don't you restate your question and give particulars about your wifi problem.

Comment: I bought some hardware that is Windows compatible, a USB that catches WIFI. I think this will help.

Comment: The hardware came with software, too. I paid money for it so I would really like to see it through.